# Kafka Cluster : Zookeeper nodes show different topic configuration information

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-topic

I have a kafka cluster with 5 zookeeper nodes and 6 broker nodes.

- Kafka version: 2.4.0
- Zookeeper version: 3.5.6

I recently changed the partition count on a topic from 12 to 36. Now that I check my zookeeper nodes, the nodes show different topic configurations.

On running `ls /brokers/topics/<my-topic>/partitions`,

- zookeeper 1,4 & 5 list 36 partitions
- zookeeper 2 & 3 list 12 partitions

When I describe the topic using `./kafka-topics.sh`, I get 36 partitions.

Somehow the 2 zookeeper nodes(2&3) have stale information. I tried restarting the zookeeper nodes 2 & 3 but that did not help.

Any help in solving the issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your Zookeeper properties and ensure each broker use the same Zookeeper connection string, also, latest versions of Kafka would use bootstrap-server with kafka-topics command, not Zookeeper